# Return the Row Number in an Index that meets a Specified Value (Excel)

Tags: excel, indexing

I have a question regarding indexing in excel. Is there a way if I define an range (in this case it will be G2:G19), can I return the row in which a specified value appears (in this case = 100)? This is the example I have:

Value

G2 = 0

G3 = 0

G4 = 0

G5 = 100

G6 = 100

G7 = 100

In this cause I want to return "4" because this is the first row with 100? Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use VBA to iterate through each cell with a for loop

Comment: Use the`MATCH` function.

Comment: Can I use criteria in the match function? So if I wanted to expand this, could I say > 0 if it's not necessarily 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Doug mentioned in the comments, the easiest way to do this is with the match function. [More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca?CorrelationId=6f57fcb5-f423-4ff0-913c-527174d9bcd4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

```
=MATCH(100,G2:G7,0)
```

It returns a relative reference so you would end up with 4.

The third number determines what kind of match to look for. If you enter an integer in the first part then the third number should be 1 to look for values less than that, 0 to look for an exact match, and -1 to look for values greater than.

Comment: Again, asking my question from above, can I update this for criteria rather than "100"? Could I put > 100 somehow?

Comment: What do you mean sorted? How so?

Comment: @pnuts No unfortunately. The range is going to be variable, user entry. I was just trying to ask in a general sense of "100". I guess I should've have been more specific, I'm just trying to identify the first row in a range that <> 0, though the values will be all the same sign, they will likely not all be the same. I may have to go the macro route

Comment: Okay, this doesn't seem to work  (MATCH("<>0",$G$2:$G$19)), what else do I need?

Comment: Okay, this looks better, not getting an N/A# error. It's returning the whole range though (showing 18)

Comment: You are correct, forgot the exact match (0). Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Way to hang in there!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have declared and opened the Excel object and you want to loop through column G.

```
startrow= 2
endrow = 19
counts = 0
Do While startrow <> endrow
 val = objWorkbook.Sheets("nameofsheet_or_index").Cells.Item(startrow, "G").Value
  If val = "100" Then
    counts = counts + 1
    Exit Do
  End If
 counts = counts + 1
 startrow = startrow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: This is actually for a sales team at my work, I'd prefer not to do any macros if possible.